# jQuery move iFrame with dynamic content breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

How to move an iFrame with dynamic content set?

After the mode, the iFrame content disappeared.

To illustrate, I've create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/trha9npw/):

```
<div id='source'>
  <p> source </p>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <iframe id='f'>

    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='dest'>
  <p> dest </p>
</div>

<button id='btnGo'> Go</button>
<script>
(function($) {
  $('#f').contents().find('html').html("<strong>Hello</strong>");
  $('#btnGo').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').appendTo($('#dest'));
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Old question, which is actually not related to twitter:

<s>I'm trying to move a twitter widget from one container to another.</s>

However, when the widget moves, it's getting blank.
Using any dom explorer, I can see that its internal iframe's body is empty.

How to workaround this?

A [reproductible fiddle shows the behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/oyah802z/).

I'm trying to move the widget using `jQuery.move`:

```
  $("#btnRepro").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").appendTo($("#right"));
  });
```

The widget is produced using this snippet (generated on twitter website:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/#dragnpoint" data-widget-id="709489444726968320">Chargement des tweets</a>
<script>
  ! function(d, s, id){var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if (!d.getElementById(id)) {js = d.createElement(s);js.id = id;js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move iframe along the DOM without losing it's content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885504/how-to-move-iframe-along-the-dom-without-losing-its-content)

Comment: regarding discovering, duplicates are available